# Sort System.Data.DataTable with multiple sort criteria

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, datatable

I have this `System.Data.DataTable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Sector", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("BBG IPC", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("Analyst", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Issuer Group", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Seniority", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Mkt Value", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("Nom Value", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("Issue Group Rating", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Current SBR", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Notches", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Forward SBR", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Probability of Downgrade", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Risk Category", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Restricted Message", typeof(string));


dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agencies", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "BB",-1, "YY", "Hight", "R1", "Comment", "gvbhjnnijnibj" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agencies", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "CC",2, "II", "Low", "R2", "Bergtrgrt", "Other" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agencies", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "EE",3, "LL", "Mid", "R1", "vggvbhjjnnjoioion", "ggvbhibniujbuhvg uvvugvghV" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Consumer", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "OO",-1, "SS", "Higth", "R3", "vgvgyhvgvjhbkj", "bibhjbhjbjhb  ubuyhbuyhb hbuhbuhbhb" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Energy", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "PP",-2, "QQ","Higth", "R1", "ertyuiop", "tfcgvhb Uvugvugvuhvh" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Energy", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "GG",-3, "FF", "Low", "R2", "gvgvgvvgfccfdxdxrtf xrtfvgh tdctfgv trcfygvh tcfyghv b ygvhb ", "ygvgubiujb" });
```

I need to Sort the table on the basis of these rules:

1st Level: Sector in alphabetic order.

2nd Level: Downgrade probability in the following order: High, Mid, Low

3rd Level: Issuer Group in alphabetic order

[image]

I've tried something like this`dt.DefaultView.Sort("Sector", "Probability of Downgrade", "Issuer Group");` but does not work. How can i do it? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using `DataTable`, as opposed to some sort of list? Usually it causes more pain than gain, but of course there can be reasons for it :-)

Comment: Having you tried the version: `DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
            dv.Sort = "[Sector], [Probability of Downgrade], [Issuer Group]";` and then inspect the `dv` variable?

Comment: To address the 2nd sort requirement (High, Mid, Low) are you able to assign an additional numerical value based on this column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following which is similar to your last request :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> probabilityStr = new List<string>() { "Hight", "Mid", "Low" };

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Sector", typeof(string));  //1
            dt.Columns.Add("BBG IPC", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Analyst", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Issuer Group", typeof(string));  //3
            dt.Columns.Add("Seniority", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Mkt Value", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Nom Value", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Issue Group Rating", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Current SBR", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Notches", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Forward SBR", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Probability of Downgrade", typeof(string));  //2
            dt.Columns.Add("Risk Category", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Restricted Message", typeof(string));


            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agencies", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "BB", -1, "YY", "Hight", "R1", "Comment", "gvbhjnnijnibj" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agencies", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "CC", 2, "II", "Low", "R2", "Bergtrgrt", "Other" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Agencies", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "EE", 3, "LL", "Mid", "R1", "vggvbhjjnnjoioion", "ggvbhibniujbuhvg uvvugvghV" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Consumer", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "OO", -1, "SS", "Higth", "R3", "vgvgyhvgvjhbkj", "bibhjbhjbjhb  ubuyhbuyhb hbuhbuhbhb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Energy", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "PP", -2, "QQ", "Higth", "R1", "ertyuiop", "tfcgvhb Uvugvugvuhvh" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Energy", 180969, "MUSTO", "Caisse des Depots", "Senior", 10114481, 1000000, "AA", "GG", -3, "FF", "Low", "R2", "gvgvgvvgfccfdxdxrtf xrtfvgh tdctfgv trcfygvh tcfyghv b ygvhb ", "ygvgubiujb" });


            DataTable dt2 = dt.Clone();

            var sectors = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Field<string>("Sector"))
                .ThenBy(x => probabilityStr.IndexOf(x.Field<string>("Probability of Downgrade")))
                .ThenBy(x => x.Field<string>("Issuer Group"))
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Sector"))
                .ToList();

            for (int si = 0; si < sectors.Count(); si++)
            {
                var probabilities = sectors[si].GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Probability of Downgrade")).ToList();
                for (int pi = 0; pi < probabilities.Count(); pi++)
                {
                    var groups = probabilities[pi].GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Issuer Group")).ToList();
                    for (int gr = 0; gr < groups.Count(); gr++)
                    {
                        for (int r = 0; r < groups[gr].Count(); r++)
                        {
                            DataRow row = dt2.Rows.Add();
                            for (int i = 0; i < dt2.Columns.Count; i++)
                            {
                                switch (dt2.Columns[i].ColumnName)
                                {
                                    case "Sector" :
                                        if (pi == 0)
                                        {
                                            row["Sector"] = sectors[si].Key;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            row["Sector"] = DBNull.Value;
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    case "Probability of Downgrade" :
                                        if (gr == 0)
                                        {
                                            row["Probability of Downgrade"] = probabilities[pi].Key;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            row["Probability of Downgrade"] = DBNull.Value;
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    case "Issuer Group" :
                                        if (r == 0)
                                        {
                                            row["Issuer Group"] = groups[gr].Key;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            row["Issuer Group"] = DBNull.Value;
                                        }
                                        break;

                                    default :
                                        row[i] = groups[r].First()[dt2.Columns[i].ColumnName];
                                        break;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is necessary change the order of the columns like u did in "dt2"? Because in this case i need to mantain the same order of the columns and structure exactly like in "dt". Thanks

Comment: I assumed that you wanted the grouped column first like your screen shot.

Comment: But after this code, the sector is present only in the first occurence. i need it present in all the rows since i need to do other extractions by sector later. I tried to delete row["Sector"] = DBNull.Value; but its the same. How can i do?

Comment: Remove the If statements and just have row["Sector"] = sectors[si].Key;

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for the `DataView.Sort` property is very similar to that used in SQL Server.

For your example, you could use this string:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "Sector ASC, [Probability of Downgrade] ASC, [Issuer Group] ASC";
```

.. and then just access `dt.DefaultView` in your code.

But you'll probably have a problem, because an ascending sort on ("High", "Mid", "Low") is going to return them as "High", "Low", "Mid". Because they're strings, it'll do it alphabetically.

The simplest solution would be to use a numeric representation of the probability, if you have one in the source database, and display High/Mid/Low but not sort by them.

Here's a LINQ workaround, if the only data option you have is the probability string:

```
// Make a dictionary to map your probability strings to integers.
var probLookup = new Dictionary<string, int>();
probLookup["High"] = 3;
probLookup["Mid"] = 2;
probLookup["Low"] = 1; 

// Convert your DataTable into an array of a new type, that has the DataRow
// plus the three things you need to sort by, as separate properties.
var temp = dt.Select().Select(row => new() {   
                                   Row = row,
                                   Sector = row["Sector"],
                                   // Map the downgrade prob. to an integer.
                                   DowngradeProb = probLookup[(string) row["Probability of Downgrade"]],
                                   IssuerGroup = row["Issuer Group"]
                                 });

// Now, sort it by the 3 properties we created.
var temp2 = temp
           .OrderBy(a => a.Sector)
           .ThenByDesc(a => a.DowngradeProb)
           .ThenBy(a => a.IssuerGroup);

// Now, fish out the Row again.
var temp3 = temp2.Select(a => a.Row).ToArray();
```

**IMPORTANT DISCLAIMER:**  The LINQ was done from memory: I don't warrant it!

Comment: Thank you Ann! But i dont understand very well how to solve the "Higth, Low, Mid" problem.

Comment: My LINQ code should take care of it, but I agree that it's a bit hard to understand!  I'll rewrite it a bit.

Comment: OK, updated. What I changed it to do was to use the **Probability of Downgrade** string as a key to a dictionary that had a numeric value in the desired order. I then sort the results by **Sector, the numeric value**, and **IssuerGroup**. I end by creating an array of `DataRow` objects, and assigning it to the variable `temp3`, which you can do whatever you need to do with.